# From which branch are contributors supposed to do 'git checkout -b' on flutter framework project

Tags: flutter, dart, frameworks

I would like to contribute to flutter framework development by fixing some issue. To do so, I just follow the steps described in the [flutter wiki page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Setting-up-the-Framework-development-environment).
I saw in some source files of the master branch that `switch` bloc format is not respected.
[Somehere in cupertino/dialog source codev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pFKO.png).

I check other branch like `flutter-3.7-candidate.10`, everything seems good.

I wonder if there is a defined branch from which we are supposed to make 'git checkout -b'.

Comment: there are few prior steps are required, I will highly recommend to check [How to contribute to Flutter (The Boring Flutter Development Show, Ep. 53)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yBgOBAOx_A)

Comment: Thanks @YeasinSheikh, I follow steps describe in the video but still have the same issue.

Comment: You can reach out to the flutter community, ig.